# How to get the result of a div which is a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have this code :

```
<div id="user"></div>
```

And actually this div is defined by the id and it is a checkbox. Do you know how can I get the result of the checkbox ?

I try this :

```
var users = $('#user');
```

But when I try this :

```
alert(users);
```

I get this :

```
[object Object]
```

Could you help me please ?

Comment: try `console.log` instead of `alert`

Comment: a div and a checkbox are different things. Do you mean your checkbox is inside that div?

Comment: Actually it is because the id is equals to user that I get a checkbox else I will not get a checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

By simply only fetching the div with jQuery, you only get the div-object. In order to fetch the checkbox-value you need to call the .val()-method;

var users = $('#user').val();

Comment: this is how you indeed get the value of a form input - but `$('#user')` appears to be a div rather than an input, so this won't work

Comment: I get nothing :/

Comment: @JackPeter3 Could you link your code to pastebin, so that its easier to get an overall look of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you give some id to your checkbox component and then retrieve it  ?
by var users = $('#user').val();

Comment: I get nothing :/

Answer (score 0):

Div doesn't hold `value` so use `data-` attribute instead like this

```js
var user = $("#user").attr('data-id')
console.log(user)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="user" data-id="abc"> Some text</div>
```